strcpy() throwing segmentation fault for unknown reasons
I'm trying to learn socket programming in C, I want to create a server that manages a chat room, to which clients can connect and send messages to everyone else
Here's the server code:
(You can skip it to get to the snippet of the important part of the code)
/* Server that manages a chat room */

// include necessary libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <netdb.h>

// definitions

// function declarations
void printaddrs(struct addrinfo *res);
void printusage();
int isdig(char c);
int isaddr(char addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN]);
int isport(char port[6]);
char *strin(FILE *stream);
int getaddrfamily(char addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // argv[1] -> address for the server to bind to, if it is 0, print a list of addrs with getaddrinfo()
    // argv[2] -> port for the server to bind to

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~ Argument validity checking - Start~~~~~~~~~~~~
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Not enough arguments\n\n");
        printusage();
        return 1;
    }
    if (argc > 3) {
        printf("Too many arguments\n\n");
        printusage();
        return 1;
    }
    if (strlen(argv[1]) > INET6_ADDRSTRLEN) {
        printf("IP address too long\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (isaddr(argv[1]) == 0) { //  is not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address
        printf("Invalid <ip addr> argument\n\n");
        printusage();
        return 1;
    }
    if (strlen(argv[2]) > 6) {
        printf("Port number too long\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (isport(argv[2]) == 0) { //
        printf("Invalid <port> argument\n\n");
        printusage();
        return 1;
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[2], "0") == 0) {
        printf("Argument <port> cannot be 0\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10) < 1024) {
        printf("CAUTION!\nBe cautious when using reserved port numbers\n");
    }
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~ Argument validity checking - End ~~~~~~~~~~~~

    struct addrinfo hints, *res;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // Use both IPv4 and IPv6
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // Use TCP/IP (not UDP)

    char addrstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = "";
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "0") == 0) { // User entered '0' as the first argument
        int status = getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[2], &hints, &res);
        if (status != 0) {
            printf("getaddrinfo(): error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
            return 1;
        }
        printaddrs(res);
        printf("Select an address to bind to: ");
        char *id = strin(stdin);

        int count = 0;
        for (; res != NULL; res = res->ai_next) {
            if (strtol(id, NULL, 10) == count) {
                if (res->ai_family == AF_INET) {
                    struct sockaddr_in *ipv4;
                    ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)res->ai_addr;
                    inet_ntop(res->ai_family, &(ipv4->sin_addr), addrstr, sizeof(addrstr));
                } else if (res->ai_family == AF_INET6) {
                    struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6;
                    ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)res->ai_addr;
                    inet_ntop(res->ai_family, &(ipv6->sin6_addr), addrstr, sizeof(addrstr));
                } else {
                    printf("error: Choosing an address of an invalid address family is not allowed\n");
                    printf("Terminating...\n");
                    free(id);
                    freeaddrinfo(res);
                    return 1;
                }
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }
        free(id);
        if (res == NULL) {
            printf("error: Couldn't find entered id\n");
            freeaddrinfo(res);
            return 1;
        }
    } else { // User entered a specific IP address
        strncpy(addrstr, argv[1], 4);
        int addrfamily = getaddrfamily(addrstr);
        if (addrfamily == AF_INET) {
            struct sockaddr_in *ipv4;
            inet_pton(AF_INET, addrstr, &(ipv4->sin_addr));
            res->ai_addr = (struct sockaddr *)ipv4;
            res->ai_family = AF_INET;
        } else if (addrfamily == AF_INET6) {
            struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6;
            printf("check1\n");
            inet_pton(AF_INET6, addrstr, &(ipv6->sin6_addr));
            printf("check2\n");
            res->ai_addr = (struct sockaddr *)ipv6;
            res->ai_family = AF_INET6;
        } else {
            printf("error: Invalid address\n");
            freeaddrinfo(res);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Server address: %s\n", addrstr);
    printf("Server port: %s\n", argv[2]);

    printf("Success!\nTerminating...\n");
    freeaddrinfo(res);
    return 0;
}

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~ Function definitions ~~~~~~~~~~~~

// prints available addresses to possibly bind to
void printaddrs(struct addrinfo *res) {
    int id = 0;
    char addrstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char ipver[30];
    for (struct addrinfo *p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) {
            struct sockaddr_in *ipv4;
            ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(ipv4->sin_addr), addrstr, sizeof(addrstr));
            strcpy(ipver, "ipv4");
        } else if (p->ai_family == AF_INET6) {
            struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6;
            ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(ipv6->sin6_addr), addrstr, sizeof(addrstr));
            strcpy(ipver, "ipv6");
        } else {
            strcpy(addrstr, "error: Invalid address family");
            strcpy(ipver, "error: Invalid address family");
        }

        printf("%d|%s\t%s\n", id, ipver, addrstr);
        id++;
    }
}

// prints the 'usage:' message
void printusage() {
    printf("usage:\n./server <ip addr> <port>\n");
    printf("<ip addr> - IPv4 or IPv6 address for the server to bind to (only dots or colons allowed)\n");
    printf("<port> - Port number for the server to bind to\n");
}

// Returns 1 if character c is a digit (0-9)
int isdig(char c) {
    switch(c) {
        case '0':
            return 1;
        case '1':
            return 1;
        case '2':
            return 1;
        case '3':
            return 1;
        case '4':
            return 1;
        case '5':
            return 1;
        case '6':
            return 1;
        case '7':
            return 1;
        case '8':
            return 1;
        case '9':
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

// Returns 1 if addr is a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address, otherwise returns 0
int isaddr(char addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN]) {
    int isipv4 = 0, isipv6 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(addr); i++) {
        // If both dots and colons are present in addrm return 0
        if (isipv4 && isipv6)
            return 0;
        if (addr[i] == '.')
            isipv4 = 1;
        else if (addr[i] == ':')
            isipv6 = 1;
        // if character is something other than a digit, dot or colon
        if (isdig(addr[i]) == 0 && addr[i] != '.' && addr[i] != ':')
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

// Returns 1 if number(5 digits) is a valid port number, returns 0 if it's not
int isport(char port[6]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(port); i++) {
        if (isdig(port[i]) == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

// Takes string input from FILE *stream - !!! result must be free()'d !!!
char *strin(FILE *stream) {
    char *str = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;

    int c;
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        c = getc(stream);
        if (stream != stdin) {
            if(c == EOF)
                break;
        } else {
            if(c == EOF || c =='\n')
                break;
        }
        size++;
        str = realloc(str, size * sizeof(char));
        *(str + i) = c;
        i++;
    }
    if (size == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    str[size] = '\0';
    return str;
}

// Returns the address family of a given valid IP address, or -1 if no dots or colons are present
int getaddrfamily(char addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(addr); i++) {
        if (addr[i] == '.')
            return AF_INET;
        else if (addr[i] == ':')
            return AF_INET6;
    }
    return -1;
}

But this is the important part:
else { // User entered a specific IP address
        strcpy(addrstr, argv[1]);
        int addrfamily = getaddrfamily(addrstr);
        if (addrfamily == AF_INET) {
            struct sockaddr_in *ipv4;
            inet_pton(AF_INET, addrstr, &(ipv4->sin_addr));
            res->ai_addr = (struct sockaddr *)ipv4;
            res->ai_family = AF_INET;
        } else if (addrfamily == AF_INET6) {
            struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6;
            printf("check1\n");
            inet_pton(AF_INET6, addrstr, &(ipv6->sin6_addr));
            printf("check2\n");
            res->ai_addr = (struct sockaddr *)ipv6;
            res->ai_family = AF_INET6;
        } else {
            printf("error: Invalid address\n");
            freeaddrinfo(res);
            return 1;
        }
    }

If the user enters 0 as the first argument, a list of possible addresses gets printed out and the user can choose one, but I wanted it to be possible to specify an address as the argument, but when I try to copy it (argv[1]) into the addrstr string, it throws segmentation fault...
I tried using strncpy instead, got the same result, however I notices that when I only specify to copy 3 characters (in case of 127.0.0.1 only the "127" part) it works like charm, but it throws segmentation fault again when I want to copy 4 characters...
Could the dot be the problem here?
TL;DR:
When I try to copy the argument argv[1] into a string addrstr previously initialized as char addrstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = "";, it throws segmentation fault.

OT: beware of strncpy, it does not do what you think it does. Read it's documentation very closely.

it's quite a lot of code. I would help to help you if you reduced it to a [mre].

strncpy is dangerous and should never be used in modern C programming. Is strcpy dangerous and what should be used instead?

@wohlstad The only important part is the one strcpy(addrstr, argv[1]);, I'm trying to copy an argument given from console into a string previously initialized as char addrstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

@BrewsLee check if the string pointed by argv[1] is not longer than the addrstr buffer by using your debugger or by adding an appropriate printf. But anyway, making a [mcve] may be some work for you, but it will definitvely help to pinpoint the problem and by doint do you might even solve the problem yourself.

You need addrstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN+1] to make room for the trailing zero.

@user207421 The value of the macro already accounts for the trailing zero. The longest possible IPv6 address is 45 characters and INET6_ADDRSTRLEN is defined to be 46.

In the big snippet, it's strncpy, but in the focused snippet (and the title) it's strcpy.  Which is it?  Is it actually crashing where you think it's crashing?  Can you use a debugger to inspect the exception to determine whether it was reading or writing and to which address it was trying to access?

In the line strncpy(addrstr, argv[1], 4); you're copying at most 4 characters from argv[1] to addrstr.
The documentation of strncpy()says:

No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if source is longer than num. Thus, in this case, destination shall not be considered a null terminated C string (reading it as such would overflow).

Your argv[1] is probably longer than 4 characters (IPv4 addresses are sequences of four numbers separated by dots, each number represented as a sequence of decimal digits; and that's a lot of characters!). Then, there will be no /0 terminator inside the addrstr array (just the first four chars (ie. bytes) of the first command line parameter, and the some junk). Then, you pass this array (this "unterminated" string) to getaddrfamily(), which calls strlen(), which looks for the /0, doesn't found it... and keeps looking, pass beyond the allocated size of the array. Sooner or later (if it's sooner it's better), that triggers the "segmentation fault".
Edit. Now I see you're using strncpy() in the complete version of the code but strcpy() in the extracted part. Which version of the code is giving you the error?

At least this problem:
Insufficient allocation
Allocation 1 too small.  No room for the null character.
        str = realloc(str, size * sizeof(char));
        *(str + i) = c;
        ...
    }
    ...
    str[size] = '\0';  // !! Outside allocation !!


Add 1 to the allocation.

Check allocation success.

Size to the referenced object, not the type.


// str = realloc(str, size * sizeof(char));
void *p = realloc(str, sizeof str[0] * (size + 1));
if (p == NULL) {
  free(str);
  return NULL;  // TBD error return details.
}
str = p;

